# R Looking up closest value in data.frame less than equal to another value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames, `lookup_df` and `values_df`. For each row in `lookup_df` I want to lookup the closest value in the `values_df` that is less than or equal to an index value.

Here's my code so far:

```
lookup_df <- data.frame(ids = 1:10)
values_df <- data.frame(idx = c(1,3,7), values = c(6,2,8))
```

What I'm wanting for the result_df is the following:

```
> result_df
   ids values
1    1      6
2    2      6
3    3      2
4    4      2
5    5      2
6    6      2
7    7      8
8    8      8
9    9      8
10  10      8
```

I know how to do this with SQL fairly easily but I'm curious if there is an R way that is straightforward. I could iterate the the rows of the `lookup_df` and then loop through the rows of the `values_df` but that is not computationally efficient. I'm open to using `dplyr` library if someone knows how to use that to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `values_df` is sorted by `idx` ascending, then `findInterval` will work:

```
lookup_df <- data.frame(ids = 1:10)
values_df <- data.frame(idx = c(1,3,7), values = c(6,2,8))
lookup_df$values <- values_df$values[findInterval(lookup_df$ids,values_df$idx)]
lookup_df

>   ids values
 1    1      6
 2    2      6
 3    3      2  
 4    4      2
 5    5      2
 6    6      2
 7    7      8
 8    8      8
 9    9      8
 10  10      8
```

Comment: Brilliant, this should neatly cover the `<= index` requirement.

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciated. I use dplyr heavily so the fact that this doesn't rely on the data.table package is helpful.